# iOS duplicate record Not Allowed

Tags: ios, core-data

I need to stop the user with alert if he/she insert a duplicated records:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3

(A          B          C)    Allowed

(B          A          L) Allowed

(A          B          C)    Not Allowed because its duplicated records
```

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newAdds;
    newAdds = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Matches" inManagedObjectContext:context];


    [newAdds setValue:club01.text forKey:@"club01"];
    [newAdds setValue:club02.text forKey:@"club02"];
    [newAdds setValue:matchDateVar forKey:@"matchDate"];


    [newAdds setValue:matchTaypVar forKey:@"matchType"];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to implement a check like that:

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName: @"Matches"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"club01 == %@ AND club02 == %@ AND matchDate == %@", club01.text, club02.text, matchDateVar];
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;

NSError* error = nil;
NSArray* tuples = [context executeFetchRequest: fetchRequest error: &error];
if ( tuples.count > 0 )
{
  // OOPS ! Entity already exists
}
```

Performance-wise, you may want to add an index for club01, club02, matchDate. It will help greatly.

Edit: you can also use:

```
NSUInteger count = [context countForFetchRequest: fetchRequest error: &error];
```

instead of executeFetchRequest. Better even.

Answer (score -1):

it's ok now.
The problem is the Date/Time could not be duplicated because the seconds.

thanx :)